# MVC3 - Change lay out based on drop down selection update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

I have a MVC3 website that displays the website name on the top header on the page. This comes from site.master page. I would like to convert that static header name into a drop down on top of the page. On selection changed - I would like to display a different site.master page(content views come completely from a different controller than the original choice). How can I do this in MVC3 web app?

Comment: what have you tried?  what are you stuck on?  do you know how to add a dropdown control?  do you know how to bind it to an event?.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all the pages uses the `_ViewStart.cshtml` found directly under the Views directory in a MVC3 Web Application project. This will be pointing to the `_Layout.cshtml` (master page of mvc) under `Views/Shared` directory.

Placing Individual `_ViewStart.cshtml` under corresponding View directories would override the default behavior. Hence if you take Home View as an example you will have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` under `Views/Home`

here `_ViewStart.cshtml` will return it's specific layout; hence the code is

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
 }
```

As you can see you will create your very own layout master called `_HomeLayout.cshtml` and place it under `Views/Shared` directory. Depending on your needs you will repeat this to the number of views you have (if you don't specify one, it will always use the default ones). Have a look at the screenshot given below. Based on your needs later you can have a dropdown to make selection of your different views.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, on the selection change redirect the window to the new url which executes the specific action method on the controller.

I don't have the actual code example, but let me try to explain in plain english

For e.g. by default you load the **Index** action method of **HomeController**, the index view uses "**site.master**". Now on the selection change, you redirect the browser to different url ("**NewHome/Index**"). **Index** view under the **NewHomeController** will have a different master page, which you can set by the following ways

put the code below

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NewHomeLayout.cshtml";
 }
```

1. into a new **_ViewStart.cshtml** file under the "**NewHome**" view folder.
2. In the **NewHome** Index view, you set the **Layout** directly with the same code mentioned above